# tying to connect external MSSQL server from Hostinger using SQLSRV

Tags: php, odbc, sqlsrv

This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

I AM GETTING THIS ERROR WHILE tying to connect external MSSQL server from Hostinger using SQLSRV

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

THIS IS MY CONNECTION STRING

BOTH ODBC and SQLSRV enabled in php

Comment: You need to contact your hosting provider to ask if they will install the ODBC driver for SQL Server into your hosting environment for you.